# react-select (AsyncSelewhen typing) not deleting

Tags: react-select

I have a dropdown using AsyncSelect that when trying to clear it up it doesn't clear.  As I have the setup right now I have to: display a previously selected value upon rendering (set by the state, which in turn gets its initial value from a prop), be able to update this value (onChange), be able to type into the input a string to search.  Right now, after having a value pre-populated, when I click on the dropdown to type and search, my input doesn't get cleared and I don't see what I input, almost as if the input wasn't allowing edits.

**Update**: for example, when I click over the drop down I see the cursor but if I hit "delete" the value is not reset.

Any help will be appreciated it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import AsyncSelect from 'react-select/async';



class DropDown extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedValue: null,
      loaded: false,
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.loadOptions = this.loadOptions.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const { value } = this.props;
    this.setState({ selectedValue: value, componentMounted: true });
  }

  onChange(value) {
    const { updateParent } = this.props;
    this.setState({ selectedValue: value });
    updateParent(value);
  }

// this returns a promise with my data
  loadOptions() {
    const { getDropDownOptions } = this.props;
    return getDropDownOptions();
  }

  render() {
    const { selectedValue, loaded } = this.state;

    return (
      loaded && (

        <AsyncSelect
          defaultOptions
          isClearable
          inputValue={selectedValue}
          onChange={event => this.onChange(event)}
          loadOptions={this.loadOptions}
          {...{ ...this.props }}
        />

      )
    );
  }
}

DropDown.defaultProps = {
  isClearable: true,

};
export default DropDown;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the selected option which is of shape `{ value : '1', lable:'apple' }` as the input value to the `<AsyncSelect/>`, there is no need to explicitly pass the input value into the component since it will be managed from inside `Select` component. Just change,

```
<AsyncSelect
   ...
   inputValue={selectedValue}
   ...   
  />
```

to

```
<AsyncSelect
   ...
   value={selectedValue}
   ...
  />
```